# Why would a user post answers and then delete them?

Tags: discussion, self-delete

On two different beta sites, I've seen the same low-rep user post an answer and then very soon after delete the answer. One answer was certainly valid with no other answer or even good comment (to my own question), the other looked reasonable but certainly a little bit like unsubstantiated opinion.

I realise I can flag these answers for un-deletion by a mod, but I'm wondering if there is some reasoning to the user's action. The account is 9 months old, but they seem to have become more active on several sites in the past few weeks. I'm impressed if these are actually bot generated answers...

Comment: September is when new students start posting. They want answers but worry about doing something they shouldn't. Maybe that's the case but otherwise we're likely guessing here just as you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, from the user's later comment, that deletion in this case was either accidental, or self-doubt...

Both of the answers I noticed are now un-deleted (one by a mod, the other I guess by the user).

Answer (score 7):

It *once* was a custom on Stack Overflow to edit the answer and replace the text with "I deleted this in favor of (other answer)", or "Didn't read the question clearly", or something like that. We knew other users with certain privileges could see the answer and wanted to leave some breadcrumbs. It has been a while since I've seen anyone do that, but it used to be quite common.

Reasons for doing it usually revolve around seeing another answer posted soon after the one you wrote, or having an "oh, duh!" moment shortly after posting. Some folks want to get an answer in *early* (see "[fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)") so they post the gist of it early, then go back and refine, ideally within the 5 minute grace period.

Mods get an automatic flag if a user deletes too much of their own content, so there's no reason to worry *too* much, but if you see an odd pattern of abuse or trollish-like behavior then you should probably flag it.

tl;dr: Don't worry too much about it, some people are more eager to get something posted than they are to refine it. And that's okay, it's cool that folks get excited about writing an answer. It just, sometimes, gets the better of us :)

Comment: Sometimes you also post an answer and later on see an answer by a different user that fully incorporates your concepts and then extrapolates on them, rendering your answer somewhat obsolete. Depending on the age of the post, it is unfeasible for the better answer to rise to the top so deleting yours helps in these cases.